# Reflections com Kotlin

Tags: funções, classes, reflexão, kotlin

Eu preciso comparar um KParameter com uma KClass, saber se o tipo do parâmetro é equivalente a minha KClass. Até agora não encontrei santo que faça isso, alguém tem a minha solução?